# is there a way to make a function to not return null when lookup from a map

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, nullable

Having a `Map<K, V>`, and need to look up by key and pass the result to a SDK's api which takes only on-null value. like:

```
fun doSomeThing(value: V)
```

The look up could be as

```
val v = theMap[key]
```

but the v is nullable now, even if the key used here is guaranteed to exist and the v will be not null.

is there a way to make function not return nullable in case need to look up from a map?

```
fun returnNotNullable(key: K): V {
   check(keyExist())
   return theMap[key]!!  // dont like the !! here
}
```

just dont want to use `!!` like  `doSomeThing(theMap[key]!!)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `?: throw IllegalStateException("Item not found")` instead of doublebang. The type of `T? ?: throw ...` will be non-nullable `T`.

Comment: you mean `return theMap[key] ?: throw IllegalStateException("Item not found")`? in `fun returnNotNullable(key: K): V`?

Comment: If you're going to use it in more than one place, you might want an extension fun

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myMap.getValue(key)`